# Resolve conflicting type in the getline function when trying to find the longest line inputted in the program?

Tags: c

I have followed an example program to create a method to spot the longest line of input and I have experienced some conflicting types for 'getline' function when I checked the types for the parameters within the getline function and examined the lines:

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline);

len = getline(line, MAXLINE)

int getline(char s[], int lim){
```

The 3 lines of the code snippet from the main program shows that the types of line and maxline remains unchanged in the 3 lines. I'm struggling to see where the conflict lies.

The declaration of the variables are:

```
char line[MAXLINE];
#define MAXLINE 1000
```

Below is the code for the entire program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main(){
    int len;
    int max;

    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0){
        if (len > max){
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }

    if (max > 0){
        printf("%s", longest);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim){
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n'; ++i){
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]){
    int i;

    i = 0;

    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your `getline` function conflicts with the GNU C Library function having the same name. If you are using _gcc_, try to compile with `gcc -ansi`. You can use other options for the language standard such as `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of the existence of another function [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), which is most likely present in your version of the standard library. It creates the conflict with your function definition. It is prototyped in `stdio.h` (which is included in your program) and present in the standard library (which is linked by default) which you're using.

Easiest way out: Use a different name for your function, like `my_getline()` or something.